# How does exponent bias make comparison easier

Tags: binary

I'm reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias) article about `exponent bias` in floating point numbers and it says the following:

> n IEEE 754 floating point numbers, the exponent is biased in the
>   engineering sense of the word – the value stored is offset from the
>   actual value by the exponent bias. Biasing is done because exponents
>   have to be signed values in order to be able to represent both tiny
>   and huge values, but two's complement, the usual representation for
>   signed values, would make **comparison** harder. To solve this problem the
>   exponent is biased before being stored, by adjusting its value to put
>   it within an unsigned range suitable for **comparison**. By arranging the
>   fields so that the sign bit is in the most significant bit position,
>   the biased exponent in the middle, then the mantissa in the least
>   significant bits, the resulting value will be ordered properly,
>   whether it's interpreted as a floating point or integer value. This
>   **allows high speed comparisons** of floating point numbers using fixed
>   point hardware.

I've also found this explanation from wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_binary) about offset binary:

> This has the consequence that the "zero" value is represented by a 1
>   in the most significant bit and zero in all other bits, and in general
>   the effect is conveniently the same as using two's complement except
>   that the most significant bit is inverted. It also has the consequence
>   that **in a logical comparison operation**, one gets the same result as
>   with a two's complement numerical comparison operation, whereas, in
>   two's complement notation a logical comparison will agree with two's
>   complement numerical comparison operation if and only if the numbers
>   being compared have the same sign. Otherwise the sense of the
>   comparison will be inverted, with all negative values being taken as
>   being larger than all positive values.

I don't really understand what kind of comparison they are talking about here. Can someone please explain using a simple example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Comparison' here refers to the usual comparison of numbers by size: 5 > 4, etc. Suppose floating-point numbers were stored with as

```
[sign bit] [unbiased exponent] [mantissa]
```

For example, if the exponent is a 2's complement 3-bit binary number and the mantissa is a 4-bit unsigned binary number, you'd have

```
1 010 1001 = 4.5
1 110 0111 = 0.21875
```

You can see that the first is bigger than the second, but to figure this out, the computer would have to calculate `1.001 x 2^2` and `0.111 x 2^(-2)` and then compare the resulting floating-point numbers. This is already complex with floating-point hardware, and if there is no such hardware for this computer, then...

So the number is stored as

```
[sign bit] [biased exponent] [mantissa]
```

Using the same 3-bit binary number for the exponent (this time biased; see [a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1796320/140607)) and unsigned 4-bit mantissa, we have

```
1 101 1001 = 4.5
1 001 0111 = 0.21875
```

But now comparison is very easy! You can treat the two numbers as integers `11011001` and `10010111` and see that the first is obviously bigger: obvious even to a computer, as integer comparisons are easy. This is why biased exponents are used.

Comment: thanks, much appreciate your efforts, it helped me a lot! Finally, I think I have a grasp of that subject :). One clarification, why do you convert `1 010 1001` to `1.001 x 2^2`, and not `1.1001 x 2^2` ? Floating point AFAIK doesn't store the leading bit, so we must add it when representing a scientific form.

Comment: @Maximus The real answer: I didn't know :) The real-sounding but false answer: it makes things easier for illustrative purposes.

Comment: In first example, if you take sign bit as 1 then it should be -4.5 and not 4.5. Secondly, you have to move radix point before first 1 and not after it i.e. .1001 and not 1.001. Well, if you don't define rules then it is okay. Actually, this is the every reason why we go ahead for IEEE format for representing floating numbers.

Comment: It seems that even the Intel Software Developer's Manual got it wrong:
"This means that
a constant is added to the actual exponent so that the biased exponent is always a positive number."

Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual
Volume 1:
Basic Architecture
4.8.2.2 Biased Exponent
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm

Comment: Additionally why does the IEEE use excess `2^(n-1)-1` instead of `2^(n-1)`? For the latter all you would need to do is to invert the MSBit from the 2-complement representation.